# Set sqldatasource string insertparameter's defaultvalue as "" creating NULL error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have an insertparameter that is a non null nvarchar(MAX) and I set it using:

```
sds_accountDetail.InsertParameters["firstName"].DefaultValue = "";
```

But it still say *"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'firstName'"*, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like its comming from the DB side, does your coulmn allow it to be null?  FirstName is a column where I wouldn't allow a null.

Comment: No column in that table allow NULL.

Comment: Have you tried using `String.Empty` to see if that works?  Like this: `sds_accountDetail.InsertParameters["firstName"].DefaultValue = String.Empty;`

Comment: Didn't work, check my answer for the work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just looking for a solution to this problem, and I encountered this page as the first Google result. I know the question is from 2012, but I decided to post for the sake of other people having the same problem. The "right" way of solving this is setting the `ConvertEmptyStringToNull` property of the problematic `Parameter` to `false`. It can be done in the .aspx file, like this:

```
<InsertParameters>
    <!-- (...) -->
    <asp:Parameter Name="firstName" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
    <!-- (...) -->
</InsertParameters>
```

or in the code-behind, like this:

```
sds_accountDetail.InsertParameters["firstName"].ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false;
```

Comment: Excellent choice, I will mark this as the correct answer and use it in the future.  Now after more than a year, the inferiority in using a white space to represent empty string is clear.  This would have been a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

"Solved" it by appending a space in the string:

```
sds_accountDetail.InsertParameters["firstName"].DefaultValue = " ";
```

Comment: Remember, thats not a null though, it may allow your code to run, but you could end up with bad data once users start editing.